# How to replace column value in Spark Streaming only if the new value isn't Null or empty?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

We have the `dataFrame` join like that:

```
  Utils.readStringDFFromKafka(spark,"sv_ships_announcements",null)
        .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), Encoders.product[ShipAnnouncements].schema).as("data"))
        .select("data.*")
        //val resutl = dfFromKafka
        .as("machine_readable_locodes")
        .join(shipsLocodes.as("human_readable_locodes"),  expr("machine_readable_locodes.lo_code == human_readable_locodes.code"), joinType="leftOuter")
        //todo join for non existing code should replace if only locodes table contains a key for that
        .withColumn("destination", $"full_name").drop("code").drop("full_name")
```

Since it is a left outer join, the replacement column `full_name` could be empty if nothing is fount in the right table. In that case we don.t like the replacement here, but instead to keep the original data:

```
        .withColumn("destination", $"full_name").drop("code").drop("full_name")
```

So how to make it replaced only with non-empty and not-NULL values?

Comment: can you provide sample data for both tables?  if full_name is empty/null after left join that means there is no corresponding row with the join key. So full_name should be taken from which row?

Comment: full_name should be machine_readable_locodes then